# Why is my neural language model performing so poorly?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to create a word-level Haiku generator using an LSTM neural network. I am scraping haikus from Reddit's r/haiku, and wanted to start with a "simple" model: my training data is the set of all haikus, flattened, and split into trigrams, such that the first two words of the trigram are the features and the last word is the label. I chose a "context size" of two just because I wanted to start with a small size, considering how small the haikus themselves are. So this is essentially a text prediction task with a small context window.

E.g the first couple (X,y) pairs (There are ~ 90,000 such pairs) look like:

```py
[('delicate savage', '/'),
 ('savage /', "you'll"),
 (" / you'll", 'never'),
 ("you'll never", 'hold')... ]
```

(I am using the '/' character to designate a new stanza, and I also added '$' to indicate the end of the haiku, to see if my model will learn such distinctions present in a haiku's format)

I then encode my sequences using an index mapping and feed this into an embedding layer when I train my model.

The model:

```py
Sequential([
    Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=60, input_length=seq_length), #seq length is 2
    LSTM(100,return_sequences=True),
    LSTM(100),
    Dense(100,kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01),activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(vocab_size, activation = 'softmax')
])
```

My performance is pretty bad: about 45% training accuracy and 15% validation accuracy. When I generate haiku sequences using a fit model, the model is often clueless and returns None.

I recognize that there are several places my model could be going wrong, but am really not sure where. I've tried various regularization techniques (dropout, L2) and modifying my neural network's architecture (# of layers and nodes) but without any luck. Before I try using pre-trained embedding, what can I do to improve my ability to predict text with my data?

If it helps, here's my [notebook](https://github.com/bfbarry/HaikuBot/blob/main/notebooks/word_level.ipynb), using a language model heavily based on [this implementation](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-word-level-neural-language-model-in-keras/).

Comment: Is this related to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/525011/best-way-to-approach-language-model-based-on-set-of-independent-sentences)? // Accuracy isn't typical for evaluating LMs, and proper [tag:scoring-rules] are better anyway. Consider evaluating your model's cross-entropy instead. // BTW - your GitHub link is 404 for me.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy  Yes, this somewhat of a followup post (also just fixed the link to the github) . I will look at my model's cross entropy. I guess it does make sense that accuracy shouldn't be used for LMs. When you say "proper scoring rules are better anyway" do you mean for statistical/ML models in general? E.g., using scores like F score?

Comment: F-score isn’t a proper scoring rule. The tag wiki has more information, like why accuracy is a bad way to score a probabilistic classifier like your trigram model.